# Show that if $f$ is continuous and non-negative on a compact set $D$ and $\iint\limits_D f\, dA=0$, then $f(a)=0$ for all $a$ in $D$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to show that if $f$ is continuous and non-negative on a compact set $D$ and $\iint\limits_D  f\, dA=0$, then $f(a)=0$ for all $a\in D$.

My first approach was to  argument by contradiction that if the is an $a_0$ such that $f(a_0)>0$ then the sup of the lower sums $\sup(L(f,P): P\text{ is a partition of }D) =\iint\limits_D  f\, dA=0$, which is a contradiction.

Is this correct? Or what would you suggest? Thanks for your help.

EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

As suggested by the comments, assume that $D$ is an open set.

Comment: For contradiction, suppose $f(a_0)>0$ then there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in B(a_0,\delta)\subseteq D$.

Comment: This is false, let $f(a)\equiv 1$ and $D=\{0\}$ be the origin in $\Bbb R^2$. Then the integral is still $0$, but the function is not. You need a compact set which contains an open set.

Comment: ...or at least $D$ has non-zero measure

Comment: Just edited the question to take this into account.

Comment: only non-zero measure is not enough. Consider $D=\{0\}\cup A_{1,2}$, where $A_{1,2}=\{x\in\mathbb R^2\ |\ 1\leq|x|\leq2\}$ is the compact annulus with inner radius 1 and outer radius 2, and $f:D\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(0)=1,f(x)=0$ elsewhere in $D$. I dont get why compactness is important there. $D$ should simply be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is a region;

Suppose $f(a_0)>0$ for an $a_0\in D$ then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in B(a_0,\delta)\subseteq D$. This implies $$0<\int_{B(a_0,\delta)} f(x) dx <\int_D f(x)dx.$$ This contradiction proves the expression.

If $D$ is not a region;

Consider $D=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ the compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:D\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=0$ when $x\in[0,1]$ and $f(x)=1$ when $x=2$. $f$ is continuous on $D$ and $\int_D f(x)=0$ but not $f(x)=0$ on $D$

Comment: This is not true if $D$ is just compact, see comments. If $D$ is open, then your idea works perfectly.

Comment: The problem is that if $D$ isn't open, we don't know whether $B(a_0,\delta) \subseteq D$ after all. Supposing that $D$ is open means that every point in $D$ is in its interior, solving that problem.

Comment: How do you know that $\int_{B(a_0,\delta)} f(x) dx <\int_D f(x)dx.$ ?

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez: $\int_{B(a_0,\delta)}f(x)dx = \int_Df(x)1_{B(a_0,\delta)}(x)dx$ and since $f$ is non-negative, $f(x)1_{B(a_0,\delta)}(x)\leq f(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(a_0)>0$.  Let $\varepsilon=f(a_0)/2>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ so small that if $|x-a_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(a_0)|<\varepsilon$, and that implies $f(x)>f(a_0)/2$.  So the integral of $f(x)\,dA$ over the disk of radius $\delta$ centered at $a_0$ is at least $f(a_0)/2$ times the area of the disk.  That is a positive number; hence the integral of $f$ over the whole region $D$ is positive.